# How do I enable the Cloud settings in Notepad++ 6.6.7 for Windows 8.1 Update 1?

Tags: windows-8.1, notepad++, dropbox, onedrive, cloud

I updated to Notepad++ 6.6.7 and wanted to move the settings to my OneDrive. But when I open Settings->Preferences->Cloud, the DropBox and OneDrive options are both disabled.

How do I enable them?

FYI, I am running Windows 8.1 Update 1 (64-bit).

---

Update:

I tried it on my 2nd laptop, running Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit) and it worked fine, I suspect it's the Windows 8.1 implementation of OneDrive which is the problem.

---

Update 2:

The workaround, obviously, is to use DropBox instead!

---

Update 3:

Except that DropBox on my WIndows 8.1 Update 1 system seems to cause File Explorer to hang...

Comment: This thread has your answer:


http://superuser.com/questions/794595/how-to-activate-disabled-cloud-settings-save-option-in-notepad#answer-794618

Comment: Not that I can see. I still can't use OneDrive or DropBox on windows 8.1 Update 1 to save my settings. The indicated thread just says to install one of the supported tools - nothing about what to do when that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you a programmer? Are you able to find OneDrive checkbox enablement condition in Notepad++ source code by yourself?

Comment: I had hoped not to dive into the source. Since no-one else has commented, I suspect it may be the only way to find out what's actually going on with my setup.