# How to activate disabled cloud settings save option in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, cloud-storage

I received an update from Notepad++ and noticed a new option that allows you to save to various cloud storage services.

[image]

However, some of the options are disabled.  How do I enable them?

Comment: Can you please confirm for me: Google Drive is effectively using the native file system / browser experience? (Google Driver synchronises the file/folder and is not a 'direct' connection.) I'm confused as to why a developer would go to the effort of placing a check-box in the UI and not attach any functionality to it. This is very strange indeed.

Comment: Exactly....
Why I can't find any link for google connection or dropbox OUTH

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For cloud based settings backup to work in Notepad++, you need to have either the Dropbox, OneDrive or Google Drive client installed and set up on your computer.

You can get them from here:

- [Dropbox client](https://www.dropbox.com/install)
- [OneDrive client](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/)
- [GoogleDrive client](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive)

Comment: I have all three installed (Dropbox, *Drive) and still have all three options disabled in my Notepad++. Any ideas?

Comment: Try performing a clean install and see if that helps? Did you set up Notepad++ an a portable installation?