# I want to use Notepad++ with Dropbox but the option is disabled even though Dropbox is installed

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, dropbox

I'm using Notepad++ on several computers, and rather than saving locally on each one I want to save to my Dropbox.  There is an option in Notepad++ to do this, but it remains disabled.  According to this ([How to activate disabled cloud settings save option in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/794595/how-to-activate-disabled-cloud-settings-save-option-in-notepad#answer-794618)) question it is disabled because I don't have Dropbox, Onedrive or Googledrive installed.  However I have both Onedrive and Dropbox installed and running and still the option is disabled in Notepad++.  Notepad++ is running as administrator and I have restarted it several times.

When I installed Notepad++ some time ago there were some different install options, could one of these be the issue?  Nothing I can find online mentions that a particular install option needed to be chosen and I'm unsure how I could now do this short of uninstalling and reinstalling Notepad++ on each computer.  I don't really want to start doing this since I'm merely speculating on the cause.

Here's a screencap showing the issue, the disabled option and the running cloud services:

[image: 1]

I'm using Windows 7 and 8.1, although I have not tried this option on 8.1 yet.

Comment: There is an exact duplicate of this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/899999/notepad-does-not-recognize-dropbox), the solution is that, there is a bug in the current version.  Use the previous version and it will work.

Comment: My apologies.  I did search but the only question that came up was the one I linked to, not this one.

Comment: The other obvious fix is to save the files to your dropbox sync folder and let dropbox handle the upload.

Comment: @krowe, thanks I can do that.  I think the extra advantage to using the option in npp is that for quick notes etc that you don't save they should still be saved to cloud.

Comment: For anyone with the same issue I can confirm reverting to version 6.7.4 bring this option back, although it only recognises Dropbox, not Onedrive.

Comment: You should report the bug then.  It also has been reported but the more people who report it the faster it will be fixed.  I should point out the functionality isn't as advanced as you might think.  All it does is performs a file copy operation of the settings file into the Dropbox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive folder.

Comment: Thanks you for your assistance Ramhound.  Does the settings file not contain the active (unsaved) tabs?  Thats basically the function I was after.  I can stop being lazy and save all my tabs but I often open ones just to make short to-do notes etc.  It seems I need to register on yet another website to report the bug so much as I'd like to I may not...

Comment: @EdtheTed: Can you post the solution as an answer?

Comment: Its seems like uncompatiblity issue between DropBox and Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Current version (6.7.5) [has a bug](http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/bugs/5195/?limit=25) causing the above issue.  Version 6.7.4 I have confirmed allows Dropbox sync, athough Onedrive still appears disabled (at least in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox integration is over rated. It just saves the settings to its own folder. Just install NotePad++ from PortableApps and install it to a Dropbox folder. Everything will be synced going forward.

Comment: Seems pretty cool to me. PortableApps version has some drawbacks (not as tight system integration)