# Files Edited by N++ 6.9.2 Not Backed Up to OneDrive Cloud

Tags: notepad++, onedrive, cloud

Having supplied the local Onedrive documents directory to the Custom Backup Directory box in the *Preferences\Backup* dialog and the same pathname to the *Preferences\Cloud* box the xml config files were copied to it as expected but even after several N++ restarts the backups of the edited files were still not copied to the cloud directory.

Note: N++ does not list cloud service names in options any more as referred to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/777159/how-do-i-enable-the-cloud-settings-in-notepad-6-6-7-for-windows-8-1-update-1), but requires a physical cloud pathname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Logged into and checked the status of the actual cloud repo via IE11.
- Downloaded the Onedrive client (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/794595/how-to-activate-disabled-cloud-settings-save-option-in-notepad#answer-794618)) but as the home button was disabled did not proceed with the business option. This might have been the magic.
- Reset the N++ settings and restarted N++ to set the cloud path ensuring it matched the backup directory for simple backup, and the files are now backed up!

As a matter of interest, running the Onedrive client *immediately after* the above process, the home/business box did not appear and the install terminated without any interactive dialog.